# Is there a way to find the RoleBinding/ClusterRoleBinding related to a serviceAccount?

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes, is there a way to find the `RoleBinding/ClusterRoleBinding` related to a serviceAccount without traversing all of the bindings?

This is very helpful when trying to solve problems related to authentication a Pod uses to request APIServer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, there is no simple way to do this with `kubectl` but it is technically supported. You can pass Custom Columns to control the resultant STDOUT to produce the information you're interested in. Then you can either specify the `-A` argument to search all namespaces or use the `-n specificNamespace` argument. Lastly, you can then `grep` the resultant STDOUT of the command to filter it accordingly if necessary.

For example, if I grab all of the bindings from the `kubernetes-dashboard` I could run this command:

```
$> kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings \
      -n kubernetes-dashboard \
      -o custom-columns='KIND:kind,NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:metadata.name,SERVICE_ACCOUNTS:subjects[?(@.kind=="ServiceAccount")].name' | wc -l
64
```

As you can see, I piped it in `wc` because over 60 results were returned and that would be awful to post on StackOverflow. However, if you use `grep` instead then you can easily retrieve more granular results. For example, this tweaked command shows that there is one CRB for the `tj` ServiceAccount resource.

```
$> kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings \
     -n kubernetes-dashboard \
     -o custom-columns='KIND:kind,NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:metadata.name,SERVICE_ACCOUNTS:subjects[?(@.kind=="ServiceAccount")].name' | grep tj
ClusterRoleBinding   <none>                 tj                                                     tj
```

You could then set up a shell alias to simplify this going forward:

```
$> alias getbindings="kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings   -n kubernetes-dashboard    -o custom-columns='KIND:kind,NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:metadata.name,SERVICE_ACCOUNTS:subjects[?(@.kind==\"ServiceAccount\")].name' | grep"
```

```
$> getbindings tj
ClusterRoleBinding   <none>                 tj                                                     tj
```

Alternatively, you could even turn it into a function which accepts two arguments, one Namespace and one ServiceAccount. Which then effectively creates your own solution to the feature request you have made. For example:

```
$> tail -n 6 ~/.bashrc
function get_bindings(){

    kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings \
      -n $1 \
      -o custom-columns='KIND:kind,NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:metadata.name,SERVICE_ACCOUNTS:subjects[?(@.kind=="ServiceAccount")].name' | grep $2
}
```

```
$> get_bindings "kubernetes-dashboard" "tj"
ClusterRoleBinding   <none>                 tj                                                     tj
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why the downvotes? There isn't a native solution but I provided a pretty sound workaround until one is developed...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality at the moment. Perhaps you can file a [feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/labels/kind%2Ffeature).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I have submit a feature request: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53248